# can't load sigma with graphology using angular

Tags: charts

I am using these combinations below to display a graph using angular v16

```
 "sigma": "^3.0.0-beta.12",
    "graphology": "^0.25.4",
    "graphology-gexf": "^0.13.0",
```

I am just trying to use this example
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/main/examples/load-gexf-file?file=%2Findex.ts%3A15%2C20

But i am seeing some weird compile error as below

```
Error: node_modules/sigma/dist/declarations/src/rendering/programs/edge-arrow/index.d.ts:3:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'packages/sigma/rendering/dist/sigma-rendering.cjs.mjs' or its corresponding type declarations.

3         drawLabel: import("packages/sigma/rendering/dist/sigma-rendering.cjs.mjs").EdgeLabelDrawingFunction<import("graphology-types").Attributes, import("graphology-types").Attributes, import("graphology-types").Attributes> | undefined;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/sigma/dist/declarations/src/rendering/programs/edge-arrow/index.d.ts:6:74 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs' or its corresponding type declarations.

6         process(_edgeIndex: number, _offset: number, _sourceData: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").NodeDisplayData, _targetData: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").NodeDisplayData, _data: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").DisplayData): void;
                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/sigma/dist/declarations/src/rendering/programs/edge-arrow/index.d.ts:6:156 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs' or its corresponding type declarations.

6         process(_edgeIndex: number, _offset: number, _sourceData: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").NodeDisplayData, _targetData: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").NodeDisplayData, _data: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").DisplayData): void;
                                                                                                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/sigma/dist/declarations/src/rendering/programs/edge-arrow/index.d.ts:6:232 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs' or its corresponding type declarations.

6         process(_edgeIndex: number, _offset: number, _sourceData: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").NodeDisplayData, _targetData: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").NodeDisplayData, _data: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").DisplayData): void;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/sigma/dist/declarations/src/rendering/programs/edge-arrow/index.d.ts:7:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs' or its corresponding type declarations.

7         render(_params: import("packages/sigma/types/dist/sigma-types.cjs").RenderParams): void;
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: ok I was able to solve it by using the older sigma release
 "sigma": "^2.4.0",

Comment: also in case anyone wants to know how to highlight edges etc for a clicked node, here is a codepend for it.

https://codepen.io/sgavathe/pen/PogpKeN